# Java. How to delete the same string objects from two string Arrays or Lists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, duplicates

It's my first question here and it's about Java. 
I would like to implement the following logic:

> I have got two string Arrays(or string Lists of string). There is an
>   array of strings (asu) - M1, M2, M3 ... As well as an array of string
>   (rzs) - M1, M2, M3 and all possible combinations thereof. The need for
>   each element (asu) (for example M1) to find an element in (rzs) (M1,
>   M1M2, ..), which contains (e.g. M1).  Example: took M1 from (asu) and
>   will start search for duplicate(contain) in (rzs). We found M1M2 in
>   (rzs), it contains M1. After that we should delete both elements from
>   arrays(lists). And I'm sorry for my English skills^^

```
String[] asu = { "M1", "M1", "M1", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M4", "M5", "M5" };
String[] rzs = { "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M1M2", "M1M3", "M1M4", "M1M5", "M2M3", "M2M4", "M2M5", "M3M4", "M3M5", "M4M5", "M1M2M3", "M1M2M4",
        "M1M2M5", "M1M3M4", "M1M3M4", "M1M4M5", "M2M4", "M2M5" };

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    work bebebe = new work();
    bebebe.mywork();
}

public void mywork() {

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(rzs));
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(asu));
    for (int i = 0; i < asu.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Итерация: " + i);
        for (int j = 0; j < rzs.length; j++) {
            if (asu[i].matches(rzs[j].toString())) {
                System.out.println(i + " элемент (" + asu[i] + ") в ASU равен " + j + " элементу (" + rzs[j] + ") в RZS");
                asu[i] = "";
                rzs[j] = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> The result does not delete items that are substring. Does not satisfy logic.
>   I will appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you'll use lists you'll have a lot better:
the delete will not ask you to take the rest of the array back, and the use of lists means less logic on your code

```
List<string> asu = Arrays.asList("M1","M1","M1","M3","M4","M5","M1","M1","M1","M4","M5","M5");
List<string> rzs = Arrays.asList("M1","M2","M3","M4","M5",
"M1M2","M1M3","M1M4","M1M5","M2M3","M2M4","M2M5","M3M4","M3M5","M4M5"
,"M1M2M3","M1M2M4","M1M2M5","M1M3M4","M1M3M4","M1M4M5","M2M4","M2M5");
public static void main(String[] args) {
work bebebe = new work();
bebebe.mywork();
}

public static void mywork() {
   ArrayList<String> tmp1 = new ArrayList<String>();  
   ArrayList<String> tmp2 = new ArrayList<String>();  
   System.out.println((rzs));
   System.out.println((asu));
   for (String curr : asu){
     for (String currRzs : rzs){
       if (currRzs.contains(curr)) {
          System.out.println(" item("+curr+") in ASU found contained in ("+currRzs+") in RZS");

      if(tmp1.contains(curr) == false)
         tmp1.add(curr);

      if(tmp2.contains(currRzs) == false)
         tmp2.add(currRzs);
       }
      } 
    }

   for (String curr : tmp1){
      asu.remove(curr);
   }

   for (String curr : tmp2){
      rzs.remove(curr);
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code is beatiful, but your solution also don't satisfy logic. As i said before, if we found M1M2 in (rzs) we should compare him with M1. And if M1 is substring of M1M2 we should delete both.
Your code doesn't do it. "Contain" statement only comparing object like M1=M1, but not strings of objects;

Comment: @EldarNezametdinov contains does equals. you can box string to your own class and override equals to do indexOf. do you want an example of it?

Comment: if it not difficult for you, because i have started learn Java only few days ago... i don't know how do it right for this situation.

Comment: program always crushed by java.util.AbstractList,it should be because we update List
+ curr is already defined, i changed it to -> curr2 and rzs.remove(curr) is ok? I can't pass a parameter currRzs

Comment: @EldarNezametdinov i forgot to close the "for" loop, i've edit it and now it shouldn't crash

Comment: looks like you have updated 1st message (or not?)
anyway if cycles for deleting outside of for() - they are not working, becase curr and currRzs is local / the same logic is incorrect, you first write down all of the matches, that is, for each M1 -> write down all the possible cases, we have obtained for a lot corresponds to the M1 M1, M1M2, and he had to be removed immediately!
this is solved by adding removal after finding - which results in an error

Comment: @EldarNezametdinov why you have to remove them as soon as you find them? i assure you that by the end of the function they will be removed. and we can put an if condition not to overgrow out lists to delete. finally we delete outside the "for (string curr : **asu**)" so we shouldn't get exception. another edit to the answer

Comment: it doesn't work. i already said that curr and currRzs are local
prooflink: http://imageshack.us/f/202/8gvy.png/
and with curr and currRzs it doesn't work too . i mean in for (x:tmp) statments

Comment: @EldarNezametdinov as your image show it doesn't work cus' you've changed the parameter's name to curr2 in the for statement but left  asu.delete(curr); and rzs.delete(curr);

Comment: AbstractList fails everytime and cycles for deleting not in base for()

Comment: and with curr and currRzs it doesn't work too . i mean in for (x:tmp) statements @@@@@

Comment: @EldarNezametdinov look at my edit now. i've ran this code and got no errors and got output

Comment: i don't know what to say, my IntelliJ Idea 12 always fails(
thx for help!